# Google Docs style commenting for Eclipse?

Tags: comments, eclipse, plugins

When editing a Google Docs document, it is possible to add to blocks of text comments which can be viewed in the sidebar. Selecting a comment highlights the corresponding text block and vice versa, which allows me to clearly see for which which comment was meant for which block. Adding these comments doesn't appear to make any changes to the documents itself.

My team and I have to deal with a lot of inconsistent and hard-to-navigate legacy code. We are mainly using Eclipse.

I want to have similar functionality in Eclipse, as well as the ability to export and import these comments. There appear to be 'Bookmark' and 'Task' functionalities, but they don't highlight the code.

Is such functionality available for Eclipse?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should place those comments inside the source code. If they are needed for understanding the code, you want to make them as accessible as possible. Unlike Google documents(or Office documents, or PDFs, or...) source files are raw text files and there is no way to embed those comments into them unless you use external files which can make things messy. Plus, I'm always against solutions that only allow to use a project with a specific IDE configuration...

### If you still want to use external comments...

Externally commenting blocks of code is something done often in code reviews, so I would look into code review plugins for Eclipse. The most popular one seems to be [AgileReview](http://www.agilereview.org/). It saves your review data in [AgileReview Source Project](http://www.agilereview.org/support/faq/#reviewData_sourceProject) XML files - which answers your "ability to export and import these comments" requirement.

The downside of this option is that now your comments are less accessible than the source code. The source code is plain text files that can be read with any IDE or text editor, while the comments can only be read with Eclipse that have the AgileReview plugin installed(unless you want to deal with the comments XML file directly). You've said that most of your team use Eclipse, so this will only cause problems with the one guy who uses something else, or when you want to just open a source file to look at some code without waiting for Eclipse to load.

Another option is to use [Review Board](http://www.reviewboard.org/) with the [eReviewBoard plugin](http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/ereviewboard)(or similar software). I seriously doubt the Eclipse interface is as good as the first plugin(I've tried neither, and eReviewBoard doesn't have a fancy website like AgileReview) - Review Board is the main product here, not the Eclipse plugin, so you'll want to do many of the management via the Review Board web app. That means you'll have to set up a Review Board server that'll sync everyone.

The main downside of this approach(beside having to setup the Review Board server, which shouldn't be that hard) is that you can only review stuff that are already committed to the SCM(AFAIK - I did not try it, I just assume that this is the case since Review Board fetches the source code to review from the SCM...). This shouldn't be that much of a problem for you, since you mainly want to comment legacy code that's already in the SCM.